# how to convert Query Builder to Elequent query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have code from query builder I want to convert to eloquent but it doesn't work

my query builder code

```
$topkabupatens =  DB::table('sekolahs as S')
        ->select('K.name', DB::raw('count(S.kabupaten) as jumlah_kabupaten'))
        ->join('kabupaten_kotas as K', 'S.kabupaten', '=', 'K.id')>orderBy('jumlah_kabupaten', 'DESC')->groupBy('K.name')->limit(10)->get();
```

my query builder code

```
$topkabupatens = Sekolah::with('kabupaten')->withCount('kabupaten')>orderBy('kabupaten_count', 'DESC')->groupBy('name')->limit(10)->get();
```

where is my mistake?

my query builder code runs but not with eloquent

Comment: Note that `with('kabupaten')` doesn't perform a join in the same way that `->join()` does. Also, `)>orderBy(...)` is a syntax error; missing the `-` from that arrow: `)->orderBy(...)`

Comment: $topkabupatens = Sekolah::with('kabupaten')->withCount('kabupaten')->orderBy('kabupaten_count', 'DESC')
            ->groupBy('name')->limit(10)->get(); 
I fixed it but it's still a problem

Comment: I figured it was a typo, but best to be sure. Can you please better describe your issue? "It doesn't work" isn't a very good description...

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
$topkabupatens = Sekolah::select('kabupaten_kotas.name')->withCount('kabupaten_kotas.kabupaten')
                ->leftjoin('kabupaten_kotas', 'Sekolah.kabupaten', '=', 'kabupaten_kotas.id')
                ->orderBy('kabupaten_count', 'DESC')
                ->groupBy('name')
                ->limit(10)
                ->get();
```